# How to add overlay which changes size/position along with zoom and position

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

I have been searching for solution on this problem for a couple of days now.
I want to add a image as an overlay(or whatever is the best solution). The image visualize a part of the map but with it's own graphics. So it's important that it scales, positions and behaves as if it were a part of the map.

The image is quite large(800x1200) so maybe it can be an advantage to use som type of tilebased solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution!! (http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/79b233ab9ec64e1e#)

I am using a overlay and in the draw method i do this.

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        if(shadow){
       return;
    }

    super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

    // convert bitmap's bounding box into pixels 
        Point top_left = new Point(); 
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(topLeft, top_left); 
        Point bottom_right = new Point(); 
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(bottomRight, bottom_right); 
        // Prepare two rectangles (pixels) 
        Rect src = new Rect( 0,0,bmp.getWidth() - 1, bmp.getHeight() - 1 ); 
        Rect dst = new Rect( top_left.x, top_left.y, bottom_right.x,bottom_right.y ); 

        // draw bitmap 
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, src, dst, null); 


}
```

// I set the geoPoints (geoPointTopLeft,geoPointBottomRight) of the picture in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have custom map tiles. Overlays are used for adding markers or small visual details which do not scale or zoom, they simply get redrawn whenever the map scales or zooms.

AFAIK MapView only currently supports Satellite and Map View tiles. It also seems like there is no API for adding custom "layers" to the map which could be another solution.

If this is a project dealbreaker for you then you could look into using something like [OSMDroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) which is a fully functional MapView replacement which uses OpenStreetMap-Data and might be easier to customize.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Maybe your right and the best way is to switch to another map api. But it's a shame. I was hoping for a solution that would work with googles mapview. It's only a small part of the map I want to overlay and I could live with making the image smaller(400x600). As long as it scales and positions with the map. I was thinking about drawing it in the onDraw in the overlay and scaling using the zoom value.